# Entity Framework Core Delete Behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

So I have these 3 tables where 2 of them(Post(Parent of Comment table as well) and Comment Table) is parent of Reaction Table.

**Post Table**:

```
public class Post
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(800)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public short Audience { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool AreCommentsAllowed { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Reaction> Reactions { get; set; }
    public int? GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

**Comment Table:**

```
 public class Comment
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(800)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateCommented { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Reaction> Reactions { get; set; }
    public long? PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public long? ReplyId { get; set; } // For replies on this comment
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

**Reaction Table:**

```
public class Reaction
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public short ReactionTypeId { get; set; }
    public ReactionType ReactionType { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateReacted { get; set; }
    public long? PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public long? CommentId { get; set; }
    public Comment Comment { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to happen is when I delete the post these records reactions, comments and comment reactions will be deleted as well. To achieve this behavior I used these configuration on fluent API.

```
builder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Comments)
            .WithOne(x => x.Post)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);


        builder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Reactions)
            .WithOne(x => x.Post)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        builder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Reactions)
            .WithOne(x => x.Comment)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

However, after running the update-database it shows the error :
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Reactions_Posts_PostId' on table 'Reactions' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Comment: maybe use different type of Reaction using [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance) with discriminator from ReactionType ... so you may have `PostReaction` and `CommentReaction` they both would in the same table and have same propeties but different type

Comment: Why did you add `Cascade` from `Comment` to `Reactions`? That's what the error complains about. You already configured cascade delete from Post to both Comments and Reactions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos prolly because Post has own Reactions and Comment has own Reactions ... they are in the same table but has different type ... and prolly when CommentId is not null then PostId is null and in the other way

Comment: @Selvin yup you're right. Please see my comment below on Carles answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you delete a Post you have two paths where you would delete a Reaction (in the relationship with Posts and with the Relationship with Comments which will also be deleted). Just set one of the Relationships DeleteBehavior to NoAction to fix this.

Comment: I actually did that. Now, when the comment has reaction and I delete the post it won't be deleted unless there are no reactions on comments. 
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Reactions_Comments_CommentId". The conflict occurred in database "TABLE", table "dbo.Reactions", column 'CommentId'.

Comment: You should probably rethink your model then... Maybe separating PostReactions from CommentReactions in different tables/entities.